# Is there such thing as "no VAT" or is it just 0%?

Tags: taxes, vat

Let's say I'm from the EU, and I sell something to somebody in the USA. Did the sale include "no VAT" or is the VAT 0%?

*Side note*: I'm from an IT background and I'm trying to figure out if a transaction always needs to have an associated VAT amount (even if it's 0), or is it really non existent in this case from an accounting / legal point of view?

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com, as it's mostly a "how should I design my software" question. From a finance perspective, what's the difference?

Comment: there are VAT exempt transactions so you need to add that case, or maybe you just program it as zero for your own sanity

Comment: @MikeHaskel It's not exactly a question about how to design it, but what is "correct" - I want to completely understand why I'm doing it this way. So I absolutely know *how*, but I want to know *why*.

Comment: @CQM Would it be VAT exempt in this case? Could you just say "if it's not a position on your invoice, it doesn't exist"?

Comment: That makes it an accounting question, I think, and out of scope.

Comment: I would not call this a programming question or an accounting question. However, I'm still having trouble understanding the question, because I don't see a difference between "no VAT" and "0% VAT."

Comment: @BenMiller Think of it that way: You fill out a form and it asks you how many children you have and you leave that field blank - does that mean that you have no children (0) or that you don't want to tell how many children you've got? So talking about taxation, if it's "VAT exempt", does that mean that the VAT rate is 0% or does it mean that VAT is simply not applicable / present in this context?

Comment: @Quasdunk: In that example, you explicitly mentioned two interpretations: either the person processing the form thinks the person who filled it out has zero kids, or they think they declined to state how many kids they have.  Those are different because in one case you know how many kids they have and in one you do not.  In your VAT example, what do you intend the two interpretations to be?  You say it could be "VAT is not applicable", but what is the functional difference between *that* and 0% VAT?  You don't appear to mean that the VAT rate is unknown (as in your children example).

Comment: Which is why I'm calling this bookkeeping. The only difference us in whether you explicitly write the zero or consider that implied by its absence

Comment: FWIW, in Canada, we have a distinction between GST/HST "exempt" goods vs. "zero-rated" goods. I would imagine there may be a similar distinction for VAT, because even though both mean no tax is charged to the customer, there is a difference in how input tax credits work.

Comment: I definitely don't think this is a programming question. The question at hand is whether there is a difference between a VAT of 0% and no VAT. It's important because it affects _how_ the programmer will  implement the difference. The _customer_ may be shown the same behavior either way, but the customer's is not the only view in play here (think record keeping and reporting). @ChrisW.Rea has a good example of why this would be important in Canada. In the US, think about the difference between a merchant who doesn't need to collect sales tax vs one who does, but has a customer who is tax exempt

Comment: These things like what you describe in Canada may exist, but if so, this is really a question about the details of tax law.  The answer could easily vary from one jurisdiction to another.

Comment: @BenMiller No, I think it's more like "the answer is either '0' or the answer does not exist at all". There is actually a huge difference from a software engineering perspective, even if the end result might look the same, as .@briantist pointed out. And yes, the details may be different for each country / tax-zone, but the question was if there is such thing as no tax. And as .@ChrisW.Rea nicely explained, there actually *is* such thing and it's not the same as 0%. This answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's complicated and if you have to deal with this professionally, you should seek advice from someone (accountant/lawyer) who knows the system.

There is such a thing as a 0% VAT rate (but not in every EU country). If you are selling goods taxed at 0%, you are entitled to reclaim the VAT you paid on your supplies and have to keep track of it accordingly. [More information on this from HM Revenue & Customs](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/vat-exports-dispatches-and-supplying-goods-abroad) in the UK.

There is also such a thing as being VAT-exempt. In that case, there is usually some other specific legal mention to include on all invoices. If your whole business is outside the VAT system (e.g. very small businesses and non-profit organisations), you do not itemize it on your own invoices, pay VAT on your supplies and cannot reclaim it. If you sell goods to such a business, you charge them VAT just like you would in a transaction with a private person.

So both exist and are distinct.